# SublimeText does not open multiple files

Tags: sublimetext3

I used to have multiple files in my project open on Sublime; but suddenly from this morning, it will open only 1 file at a time; if I open file2, file1 disappears! How can I fix this?! Please help!

Comment: Could you post some screenshots to clarify the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description, my guess would be that you're opening files by selecting them in the side bar, in which case your problem stems from the `preview_on_click` setting.

```json
// Preview file contents when clicking on a file in the side bar. Double
// clicking or editing the preview will open the file and assign it a tab.
"preview_on_click": true,
```

This setting defaults to `true`, as seen here. When it's turned on, single clicking a file opens a preview tab instead of opening the file directly. The preview opens in a `transient` view. This is visualized by having the name of the file *italicized* in the text on the tab.

Every time you single click on some other file, if there is already one of these `transient` views open, the contents are replaced with the new file that you clicked on as a new preview.

If you double click on a file in the side bar, it will open "normally" instead of as a *preview*. Additionally, making any edits to a `transient` preview will promote it to a normal view (i.e. along with being dirty you'll see the tab name no longer is *italicized*).

You can also set the above setting to `false` to turn off the preview behavior, in which case single clicking on a file will do nothing.